# Is there an Old English-derived word for change/alter/modify?

Tags: etymology, old-english

Why is there no word for **change** / **alter** / **modify** that is historically Germanic (that is, existed in Old English)? All of these are historically Latin of latin derivation.

The nearest from Old English that I could find was perhaps "**wend**," but that does not seem to be in everyday usage nor does it seem to be of the same meaning.

Comment: Regardless of their extraction, they’re English words now! :)

Comment: Many Old English words that survive have changed their meaning.

Comment: 'wend' in modern English ('to go in a particular direction') is cognate with 'went' (3rd person plural past of 'to go'), but is also cognate with Modern German 'verwandeln' =  'to transform'. As you note, 'wend' is rarer and really has nothing to do with 'changing'.

Comment: Might ***wrought** [iron]* be a relevant term here? Cognate with both ***work*** and ***wreak***, I think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'wrought' means 'made' so whatever action has been done. 'to work' as in 'to work the metal' is much more in the ballpark of changing something willfully (though that is a bit more specific than just plain 'change/alter/modify'

Comment: @Mitch: As I recall, it was Pinker who told me ***wrought*** was just another alternative to ***worked*** or ***wreaked*** for this highly irregular verb. I've never looked into it in OED though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word of Old English origin with the closest meaning in current usage would I think be *[shift](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shift),* from Old English *sciftan.*

Answer (score 2):

**Shape** derives from Old English; the [OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/177500) concisely says of its origin, "A word inherited from Germanic." In modern English, it means several things, including *changing* or *modifying* something, often for the better. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shape), passim:

> 3. : to adapt in shape so as to fit neatly and closely / *a dress shaped to her figure*
>    [...]
>
> 5a. : to make fit for (a particular use, purpose, etc.) : adapt / *shape
> the questions to fit the answers*
>
> b : to determine or direct the course or character of / *events that
> shaped history*
>
> c : to modify (behavior) by rewarding changes that tend toward a
> desired response

Shape is quite versatile and common in English. For example, colloquially, I could say *shape up or ship out* ([Wikitonary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shape_up_or_ship_out)), or I could *shape* policy ([LSE](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/impactofsocialsciences/2019/07/02/evidence-matters-but-ideas-shape-policy-in-more-fundamental-ways-than-we-might-realise/)).

In Old English, *scieppan* was a word for creation as well as shaping, such that God was called the *Scieppend* or the Shaper (Barney, *Word-Hoard: An Introduction to Old English Vocabulary*, p. 35).

Answer (score 1):

I think 'wend' is a good choice. I have a book on my desk in German and 'wend' is used in this way too: "Magdeburg - **Wend**ezeit und Neu Beginn" (Magdeburg - Changing Times and a New Beginning). It describes the city's shift from the East German system to the West German one in the early 1990s.

Answer (score 1):

wrixlan is cognate with German wechseln and has just that meaning. wordum wrixlan is the poetic phrase meaning to compose poetry by shifting and braiding words together.